# Is there an equivalent to .Net MVC Areas in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm transistioning from a heavy background in .Net Web Forms and MVC 5+ into learning Java and Spring Boot for work.

I'm developing a Dashboard in Spring Boot where all the controllers will map to a url under the same parent path "/dashboard/home" etc.

In .Net I would create a folder that matches the area name "Dashboard" then I would add a class that inherits from AreaRegistration to give the area it's name.  Then any controller I create that is in that name space would automatically route to /DashBoard/Home etc based on the name of the controller.

To set it up I would call RegisterAllAreas.

Is there something like this in Spring Boot?  Or do I need to completely relearn how to better structure a dashboard using all new concepts and I just haven't got that far yet?